# How to remove empty xml elements except few specific empty tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml with data. I need to remove all the empty tags which do not have values. But I do not have to remove 2 specific xml tags even the tags are with empty values.

```
 <Executive>
 <title></title>
<executivename></executivename>
</Executive>
```

My xml is big with lot of elements, but the above 2 elements (title & executivename) I do not have to remove even they have empty values. Below is my xslt code I used to remove all the tags with empty values. But I do not have clue how to exclude the above mentioned 2 elements from this.  Can any one please help me on this?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match=
    "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) 
     and normalize-space()='' 
      ]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

After so many trail and errors I found the way. I have added **not(self::title)** and **not(self::executivename)** as below that excludes these 2 elements from the empty tag removal logic.

```
<xsl:template match=
    "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and not(self::title) and not(self::executiveName) 
     and normalize-space()='' 
      ]"/>
```

If any one propose more optimized solution that will be great help.

Thanks!!